# Mock ServerSocket in Spring Boot JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, junit5

I'm trying to mock a socket connection and just verify if the order of the called methods is correct.

Here's my client:

```
@Component
public class Communicator extends Thread {

public void startTCPConnection() {

        logger.debug("Trying to connect...");

        try {
            client = new Socket();
            client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), reconnectTimeout);
            clientConnected = true;
            startListener(); // FIRST METHOD TO VERIFY
            out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            login(); // SECOND METHOD TO VERIFY
        } catch (Exception e) {
            clientConnected = false;
            isLoggedIn = false;
            utility.sleep(reconnectTimeout);
            startTCPConnection();
        }
    }

    public void startListener() {
        listener.start();
    }

    public void login() {
        String loginSequence = "asdf";
        send(loginSequence); // THIRD METHOD TO VERIFY
    }

    public void send(String message) {...}

    // FOURTH METHOD TO VERIFY
    public void handleMessageFromServer(String message) {
        
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            handleLoginResult(message);
        } else {
            handleMessageAfterLogin(message);
        }
    }
    
    // FIFTH METHOD TO VERIFY
    public void handleLoginResult(String message) {
    
        if (isLoginSuccessful(message)) {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            startHeartBeatSender();
        }
    }
   
    public void startHeartBeatSender() {...}

}
```

And my unit test:

```
@Spy
    private Communicator communicator;

@Test
    public void testStartTCPConnection() throws IOException {
        setupProperties();
        communicator.start();       
        verify(communicator).startListener();
        verify(communicator).login();
        verify(communicator).send(correctLoginString);
        verify(communicator).handleMessageFromServer(correctLoginResultString);
        verify(communicator).handleLoginResult(correctLoginResultString);
        verify(communicator).startHeartBeatSender();
```

So basically I want to have this order:

1. start thread (startTCPConnection)
2. startListener
3. login
4. send
5. handleMessageFromServer // receive OK from server
6. handleLoginResult // interpret the response from server as Login OK
7. startHeartBeatSender // start another thread

At the moment it dies at `logger.debug("Trying to connect...");` I am getting a "Wanted but not invoked" exception.

The usual usage is having a third party server running and then just launching my own spring boot service that connects to the mentioned server.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not designed for testing (at least not the stuff you want to test). `new` operator always is a sign that you can't test this invocation.

Try to redesign your code so it uses an injected `Socket` instead of creating it with `new`, so you can inject a mock there instead and your test does not rely on the `.connect` to acually work.

You also can try to inject a factory for `Socket` if direct injection doesn't work because you need the socket more than once per instance of your class. For the test you can then inject a mock factory that returns a mock `Socket`.